# Lightweight PHP server to bundle with application?

Tags: php, html

Does there exist some sort of PHP server that can be bundled with a locally-deployed application? It sounds wonky, but the end result is I can't use a remote web server to do anything. Clients will be downloading a package, and the plan is to use a Java backend that reads from a flat file. The flat file contains settings and is modified through a GUI written in HTML/JS, and this is where the server would come in. The forms in HTML should be able to submit to the server, which does a simple file write to the flat file.

Is there any simple, lightweight server that has that simple feature? When running the executable for the application, it would start the installation process for the server before moving the web GUI files to the appropriate locations.

Note that I'm doing this for a client, so I can't quite change the reqs and would rather not discuss their effectiveness. I would be ever thankful if people had suggestions for the server though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out roadsend php. 
It can compile php scripts into a binary with its own build in server.
https://github.com/weyrick/roadsend-php

Answer (score 5):

Since PHP 5.4, PHP have a built-in web server and this works on any system where PHP binaries exists.

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

I can't think of any lighter server...

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: PHP built-in web server doesn't really nor is it intended to replace apache, hence it wont always

Answer (score 2):

Nanoweb might do the trick for you, it's an HTTP server written in PHP. So long as the client has a PHP install you should be able to package things up nicely. In fact with a little extra effort you should be able to package up the PHP binary along with your code.

Nanoweb: http://nanoweb.si.kz/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a java backend, what do you need php for?

You could simply bundle a small java based webserver.
http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I created a small web interface for Transmission (mac/linux bittorrent client) that needed to run a local web server with a custom PHP setup. I used [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) + php w/ fastcgi. When zipped up, I believe, it weighted in at <3MBs. If you don't need to run any PHP lighttpd is only a few MB's (and light on resources) and offers a very flexible configuration.

Source: http://svn.recurser.com/transmission/trunk/cocoa/

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Java, you may want to look at [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), an implementation of PHP and many common extensions in Java.  It's a bit restrictive, but it may fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Like unomi, I don't really understand the situation, but I'll assume you do...

Apache is by far the most popular and best-tested platform on which to run PHP, but in theory it should run on any web server that supports CGI/FastCGI. Alternatives include Lighttpd, nginx, and a few dozen others.

Whatever you choose, the key is to pre-configure it and keep it self-contained in its own folder. I think Apache would easily work here. Set it to port 43948 or something; remove all unnecessary modules; pare down the httpd.conf to its most basic requirements; allow only local connections; and write clickable scripts (.bat or .sh or what have you) to start and stop it.

Answer (score 0):

[This project is an interesting option](http://code.google.com/p/php-webserver/)...

> An embeddable web server designed for (and written in) PHP. it handles
>   the control of the assigned port, setting common environmental
>   variables (such as $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE) and calling a
>   function or method in your application to delegate the request.
>
> The web server is able to be packaged in, and controlled from, your
>   application. Therefore eliminating the requirement that your user have
>   a standard web server installed and configured to use your web
>   application. Combined with a database such as a flat-file database, a
>   Berkley DB or SQLite, PHP Embeddable Web server can remove the need
>   for the user to have any specialised libraries installed, except PHP
>   (which is preinstalled in many Unix and Linux distros).

I have used this.  It does work..  It is cool.  As easy as...

```
# php server.php
```

You kind of have to get your hands dirty..  but it's TINY, a single file, and HIGHLY configurable...  Word of warning though.. don't bother with this unless you know what a header, a class, a method, and an object, etc... And be prepared to apply that knowledge.